# Событие RetrieveVirtualItem срабатывает несколько раз для отрисовки строки

Tags: c#, listview

Событие `RetrieveVirtualItem` для `ListView` в виртуальном режиме, срабатывает несколько раз для того, чтобы отрисовать одну строку. Не могу понять почему?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на [stackowerflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073209/prevent-events-from-firing-multiple-times-from-single-action). Решение проблемы, предложенное по ссылке, подразумевает добавление небольшой задержки.

Comment: не совсем понял, т.е событие срабатывает по таймауту?!

Comment: Нет. Решение проблемы, предложенное по ссылке, подразумевает добавление небольшой задержки.

Comment: А если сделать переменную в которой будет храниться значение индекса и если оно повторяеться то не обрабатывать заново

int index = -1;

        private void ReplaysList_RetrieveVirtualItem(object sender, RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs e)
        {
           
            if (e.ItemIndex != index)
            {
                info = repl.Information(e.ItemIndex);
                index = e.ItemIndex;
                item = new ListViewItem(info.Time.ToString());
            }